# Error classeswithdexfordebug

Tags: android-studio

Como puedo solucionarlo? Ya intente con el multidexenabled true y me lanza otro error

[image]

Comment: Agrega tu build.gradle por favor.

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]

también esta relacionado al limite de los 65k metodos, agrega dentro del bloque `defaultConfig`  la definición del soporte multidex en tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...    
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}    
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**es importante sincronizar tu proyecto con el archivo `build.gradle`**

`File` > `Synchronize`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo solucione